# В чём преимущество Spring перед Jakarta?

Tags: spring, java-ee

Недавно из-за производственной необходимости немного освоил `Jakarta EE`, а так обычно Android занимаюсь. На мой взгляд довольно удобный и качественный фреймворк. Но вижу, что около 90% рынка контролируется `Spring` и лишь оставшиеся 10% `Jakarta EE`. Такой вывод делаю исходя из имеющихся на рынке вакансий.
Как так вышло? Ведь `Jakarta EE` это набор стандартов и спецификаций, частным случаем которого собственно и является `Spring`. При том что код для `Spring` отличается.
Вроде `Spring` можно запустить на любом "утюге", а для работы с `Jakarta EE` требуется соответствующий контейнер, коих впрочем довольно много. Информацию по `Spring` несколько проще искать. Но едва ли эти обстоятельства стали причиной популярности `Spring`.

Работать с `Jakarta EE` довольно легко и приятно, но мучает вопрос, почему 90% рынка именно за Spring?

P.S. Собственно, ещё одна странность даже здесь нет тэга `jakarta`, но есть тэг `spring`. Хотя конечно можно использовать тэг `java ee`

Comment: Да вы в своём вопросе написали и ответ. Когда-то java-ee была сложна, spring получился намного удобнее для разработчика и завоевал рынок. Теперь java-ее не такая страшная, но время ушло, spring имеет много наработок и большое сообщество, найти решение своей проблемы гораздо легче